# `render partial: 'foo', collection: @foos` without a line break `%br` between each `foo`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have in my `app/views/bar/index.html.haml` the following

```
%p= render partial: 'foo', collection: @foos
```

the following in my `app/views/bar/_foo.html.haml` partial:

```
.foo
  .title
    %h3= foo['name']
  .image¬
    = image_tag (foo['image'])['url']
  %p.description
    :erb
      <%= foo['description'] %>
  %span.price= number_to_currency foo['price'].to_i
```

and the following in my `app/assets/stylesheets/bar.css.sass` stylesheet:

```
.foo
  border: 2px solid black
  border-radius: 5px
  background: #FAF7F7
  text-align: center
  width: 30%
  li
    text-align: left
  img
    max-height: 90%
    max-width: 90%
```

and I end up with each `.foo` div on a new line.  Is the break being caused by css or haml or how I am rendering partials?  How do would I configure it so as many `.foo` divs will render on a single line before a new one is displayed on a new line?

Comment: You are rendering your `foo` collection inside a single top-level `<p>` tag. Your `%p= render partial: 'foo', collection: @foos` should just be `= render partial: 'foo', collection: @foos`.

Comment: No, changing `%p= ...` to `= ...` does not fix the issue I am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up with each .foo div on a new line.

`div` elements are block-level elements. They're `display` is set to `block` by default, meaning they do not render side-by-side or "inline".

If you want them to display inline, you'll have to manually force them to do so by either floating them or setting their `display` property to `inline`.

> How do would I configure it so as many .foo divs will render on a single line before a new one is displayed on a new line?

You want to make your `<div class="foo">` elements float, via something like the following:

```
div.foo
  float: left
```